# What is the equivalent of the bin directory for Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there an equivalent to `bin` for Windows? If so, how can I access it from the command prompt?

Comment: You need to elaborate a bit more... What are you looking for and trying to achieve?

Comment: `bin` is not special, it is just listed in the `PATH` environment valuable. Microsoft's Windows also has this variable. Only difference is that it uses `;` instead of `:`, and there is an implied `.` at the begging for added insecurity. So have a look in this variable. You can also edit it to add a `bin` directory.

Comment: Amazing what a good edit can achieve. :P

Comment: @MichaelFrank Especially when you make assumptions and add things the OP didn't ask about (ie: "can it be created in Windows").  We should be careful of that.

Comment: Or making the title ambiguous by removing a keyword like "directory".  At first I thought the topic was about a file type.

Comment: Hmm.. good points.

Comment: I think it would be `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)`

Comment: /bin contains basic, every day command line programs that come with the OS. The closest thing to that on Windows is c:\windows\system32 because it has the same types of programs and they come with the OS.  He also specifically asked how to access that directory. "cd c:\windows\system32". I don't understand how some of the discussion has gone way off in the wrong direction, especially discussing things that weren't asked.

Comment: /bin is special https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: for me, creating a "bin" folder in Windows, will help me for this: ...Windows users should download the "Latest Xerces-C++ Binary Package for Windows". Unzip the files, and locate the SAXCount.exe program in the bin folder. This is a command-line utility that will validate your GPX file...

Comment: @RyanBabchishin it's only special in FHS. Nothing requires a Linux distro to follow FHS, and it's even less common in real Unix. Did you see this in that link: *Linux distributions (and other operating systems) can voluntarily conform to the FHS*

Comment: `bin` and `/bin` are different

Answer (score 43):

There's nothing actually special about `/bin` on Unix/Linux at all. It's just the location where executable files (including scripts, which aren't actually **bin**ary files) are placed *by convention*, and it is included in the `PATH` environment variable by default for all users. As Ryan says, the `\Windows\System32` directory on Windows is also in `PATH` for all Windows users (and, even if it isn't, Windows' program loader will search there anyhow).

You can easily create your own equivalent of `/bin` on Windows. To make it system-wide, place it somewhere like the root of the file system (as in `C:\bin`) or under an already-restricted location like `\Windows\System32\bin`), and add it to the `PATH` environment variable for all users. For a per-user location, create the directory in your own profile (`%USERPROFILE%\bin`) and add it to your account's `PATH` environment variable. Windows combines the per-user and system-wide `PATH` environment variables, so anything in the machine `PATH` variable is also added to any user's `PATH`, but not the other way around.

Of course, you'll have to add files / scripts / shortcuts / symlinks to your `bin` directory yourself. Windows installers don't expect such a thing, and won't put files there automatically the way that Linux installers will usually do.

Comment: I wouldn't put a `bin`-like directory inside System32. That's the OS' domains. Better put it elsewhere, like your suggested c:\bin, and recreate the ACLs. Doing so shouldn't take more than a minute or two if you know your way around the ACL interface; slightly longer otherwise, but still not a long time.

Comment: I would add, that the standard way to get user-installed CLI tools accessible from the command prompt is adding their installation directory (Likely in %ProgramFiles%) to the PATH.

Comment: Windows does *not* combine environment variables with the same name -- normally user-level environment variables override system-level ones. `PATH` is a special case and AFAIK the only one treated that way by Windows.

Comment: The OP never asked about creating a bin directory or environment variables... talk about off-topic.

Comment: With all due respect, asking about "an equivalent to `bin` for Windows" is asking about nothing *except* environment variables, **because that is all that `/bin` is, a folder in the `PATH` environment variable**. There are user conventions around how you *use* folders like `/bin` (or `%WINDIR%`, or `%WINDIR%\System32`), but the system does not know or care about them; all it cares about (in this context) is the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: The `/bin` folder is not just some random folder in PATH, its use is defined in the the [filesystem hierarchy standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) in linux, commonly seen on linux systems with `man hier`. Asking about a `/bin` folder equivalent is not asking about folders in PATH in general, it's obviously asking about folders where binaries are conventionally stored.

Comment: @JohnCramerus FHS is an optional thing. There are lots of Linux distros that don't follow FHS. And most Unix implementations don't use FHS either

Answer (score 10):

The `bin` directory in Unix-like systems contains the programs of the system and the installed ones, but in Windows, system programs are located in `C:\Windows\System32` and installed ones are likely located in `C:\Program Files`.

Answer (score 7):

If you're referring to bin, like in Unix/Linux, not quite. Windows doesn't use the FHS as shared by different Unix variants. Though Windows does keep stuff all over the place, just like Unix does.

The closest thing to /bin might be c:\windows\system32

```
cd c:\windows\system32
```

Comment: Neither Windows nor Linux (or the FHS) "keeps stuff all over the place". Windows uses primarily the System32 directory and the (nowadays two) Program Files directories to keep things reasonably orderly. In Linux (and many other Unix-like systems) you have `bin` (common user tools) and `sbin` (conventionally, system administration tools) under each of the root directory, /usr and possibly /usr/local, depending on system importance of the tool. (Both /usr and /usr/local can be separate from the root file system.) Windows doesn't have as clear separation in the file system between types of tools.

Comment: I think you just proved my point, there are many places where executables are stored. It is not random, if you think that's what I meant. My Linux desktop has 479 directories below /usr alone that contain executable files of some sort. If I picked through it, I guess some files would be inappropriately marked as executable, but you get the idea. The FHS specifies 7 standard parent directories that can be used for executable storage, many of which can have sub directories. Windows is similar, as it stores executables in several places under c:\windows and in c:\Program Files.

Comment: There are 6 entries in the PATH variable by default on Ubuntu systems.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, it's not clear exactly you mean by "equivalent", but many of the commands commonly used on the command line are either built into cmd.exe (dir, copy, type, mkdir, etc) even when the Unix equivalent would be in /bin, and others (findstr, net, mountvol, shutdown, tasklist, etc) are mostly located in (typically) C:\Windows\System32 (32-bit versions on 64-bit systems in c:\Windows\SysWOW64).

A list of commands can be shown with the `help` command, this includes some that are built-in to cmd.exe and some that are external programs.

Answer (score 2):

I have been maintaining servers for almost 30 years both windows and Linux.  For some reason at the beginning I started creating a bin folder in the root of c: and I always put all my scripts and utilities that I use to maintain the server.  Sometimes I added to the Path but not always.  Guess I always like the idea of a folder called bin on both systems to put my scripts in.

But yeah, nothing magical about it you can do something different on each system.

thanks,